# Can i translate the Yes/No in a boolean switch slider from jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, api

I have a switch button slider with Yes/No option.

The following is the html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Yes/No or True/False question - Boolean question, jQuery Survey Library Example</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/survey-jquery@1.8.58/survey.jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/survey-core@1.8.58/modern.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css"></head>
    <body>
        <div id="surveyElement" style="display:inline-block;width:100%;"></div>
        <div id="surveyResult"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the following javascript file

```
Survey
    .StylesManager
    .applyTheme("modern");

var json = {
    questions: [
        {
            "type": "boolean",
            "name": "bool",
            "title": "Please answer the question",
            "label": "Are you 21 or older?",
            "isRequired": true
        }
    ]
};

window.survey = new Survey.Model(json);

survey
    .onComplete
    .add(function (sender) {
        document
            .querySelector('#surveyResult')
            .textContent = "Result JSON:\n" + JSON.stringify(sender.data, null, 3);
    });

$("#surveyElement").Survey({model: survey});
```

I took the code from [here](https://surveyjs.io/Examples/Library/?id=questiontype-boolean&platform=jQuery#content-js).

Can i translate the Yes/No to Ja/Nein (German)?
There are no id's. So i cant use the replace function. Is this doable in some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `locale` setting like this:

```
Survey
    .StylesManager
    .applyTheme("modern");

var json = {
    locale: "de",
    questions: [
        {
            "type": "boolean",
            "name": "bool",
            "title": "Please answer the question",
            "label": "Are you 21 or older?",
            "isRequired": true
        }
    ]
};

window.survey = new Survey.Model(json);

survey
    .onComplete
    .add(function (sender) {
        document
            .querySelector('#surveyResult')
            .textContent = "Result JSON:\n" + JSON.stringify(sender.data, null, 3);
    });

$("#surveyElement").Survey({model: survey});
```

Here's a list of localizations that You can use:
https://github.com/surveyjs/surveyjs/tree/master/src/localization

Comment: Note that you can potentially extend this by using [`navigator.language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/languages), but note that it's unsupported in IE